# Replace string with null in SAS

Tags: sas

I have this column with table named 'price' in SAS studio.

```
ID   Price 
1    12.90
2    12.30
3     N/A
4     NA
5   NoValue
6    97.02
7    87.45
```

I plan to replace all strings (N/A, NA, NoValue) in the dataset with SAS null values. May I know how could I start with PROC SQL?

Comment: Is price a character or numeric column?

Answer (score 1):

SQL:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
        CASE
            when(upcase(Price) IN("N/A", "NA", "NOVALUE") ) then ''
            else Price
        END as Price
    from have
    ;
quit;
```

Data step:

```
data want;
    set have;
    if(upcase(Price) IN("N/A", "NA", "NOVALUE") ) then call missing(Price);
run;
```

Comment: Btw, is there a way to make it that if there is a string in Price then replace with missing values?

Comment: Use `anyalpha()` to detect alphabetical characters. Your column is already character. If you want to convert it entirely to a numeric column, use `Price_num = input(price, ?? 8.);` SAS will automatically set strings as missing, and `??` will suppress any invalid numeric value warning messages when it tries to convert the string.